Unable to call component method. Public method [mountInfolistAction] not found on component filament
I am developing a Laravel application using Filament. I have a custom Infolist in a PmoResource where I want to add a custom action to create milestones. The action is supposed to open a slide-over form to capture the milestone details. However, I am encountering the following error when clicking the action:
    use Filament\Infolists\Components\Actions;
    use Filament\Resources\Resource;

    class PmoResource extends Resource 
    {
        public static function infolist(Infolist $infolist): Infolist
        {
            return $infolist
            ->schema([
                Fieldset::make(__('Details'))->schema([
                    TextEntry::make('description')
                        ->label('')
                        ->extraAttributes(['class' => 'size-20']),
                ])->columnSpan(4),

                ViewEntry::make('')
                    ->view('infolists.components.target')->columnSpan(2),

                Section::make('milestones')->label("")
                    ->headerActions([
                        Action::make('create-milestones')
                            ->icon('heroicon-o-plus')
                            ->iconButton()
                            ->name('create-milestone')
                            ->form(static::myForm())
                            ->action(function (array $data, $record) {
                                $record->milestones()->associate($data);
                                $record->save();
                            })
                            ->slideOver(),
                    ])
                    ->schema([
                        RepeatableEntry::make('milestones')->label('')
                            ->schema([
                                TextEntry::make('id')->label('')->columnSpan(1),
                                TextEntry::make('title')->label('')->columnSpan(4)
                                    ->extraAttributes(['class' => 'font-bold']),
                             TextEntry::make('start_date')->label('')->columnSpan(5),
                                TextEntry::make('priority')->label('')->columnSpan(2)
                          ->icon(fn($state) =>  Helper::priorityIcon($state)),
                                ])
                                ->columns(12)
                                ->columnSpan(4),
                        ])->columnSpan(4),
                ])->columns(6);
        }
    }

ViewPmo Class
I use ViewRecord to display the record and manage the active tab from top navigation bar. Here's the class:
    use Filament\Resources\Pages\ViewRecord;
    use Filament\Infolists\Concerns\InteractsWithInfolists;

    class ViewPmo extends ViewRecord implements HasInfolists
    {
        use InteractsWithInfolists;

        protected static string $resource = PmoResource::class;
        public string $activeTab = 'overview';
   
        public function switchTab($tab)
        {
            $this->activeTab = $tab;
        }

        public function pmoInfolist(Infolist $infolist): Infolist
        {
            if ($this->activeTab === 'overview') {
                $infolist = PmoResource::infolist($infolist);
            }

            return $infolist
                ->record($this->record);
        }
    }

What I Have Tried:

Checked the $record context to ensure it is passed correctly to the action.
Used ->slideOver() for the form display.
Verified that myForm() is returning the correct form structure.
How to resolve this error?
Questions:
How can I properly register and execute the custom action on the Infolist?
Why does the error mountInfolistAction not found occur, and how can it be resolved?
Is there a different approach to defining actions for Infolist components in Filament?

